# Deploy and autorun Android application from Git

Tags: android, git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have some number of Android devices in real world, I want to deploy and run new versions of application from git on it.

Currently I use [Bitrise](https://www.bitrise.io/) to run tests and .apk compilation upon commits, how can I deploy that binaries on my devices and autorun it without user interaction?

I don't know such services/application, but I think there are such services/tools in the world, just I don't know about it.

**Edit 1:**
My devices are not connected physically, so I can't run gradle to deploy new builds there, devices have access to internet, but they have no direct cable connection to build server.

Comment: Please do more research. Git is a distributed source control tool, NOT a build and deployment tool. Even the tool 'Bitrise' has a CLI tool which may be appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Does you phones connected to CI or there are "remote testers"

Comment: @once2go, I may connect it to any CI, my phones, but I need to install/uninstall application without user interaction

Comment: Git just provides stroboscopic snapshots of your file system.

Answer (score 0):

If your devices connected to CI build machine you need setup execution:

1. get device list adb devices

1.1 Install app with gradle  like "./gradlew installDebug"

1.2 Install app with adb "adb -s your_device install your_app.apk"

2. Then run specific activity "adb -s your_device shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName"

You can write shell script or even create gradle task for this.

Comment: I added "Edit 1": My devices are not connected physically, so I can't run gradle to deploy new builds there, devices have access to internet, but they have no direct cable connection to build server.

Comment: Does your devices placed to common local network with CI machine? 
You can setup adb via TCP, theoretically you can forward adb ports to remote devices

Comment: No, they are not connected to the same local network, that's why I'm looking for 3rd party services that can make such "updates" to applications.

Comment: You need install your own service manually, similar to Instant App, wich can download your signed!!! build variant from any sources and will be installed progrannatically like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically